# Booting network without full network configuration

Tags: 14.04

i wanted to setup a static-ip address for my computer

so i  edited /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.113
gateway 192.168.1.255
netmask 255.255.255.0
dns-nameservers 127.0.1.1
```

but after restarting the UBUNTU 14.04 LTS 
the network manager is stop working and cant see network manager icon

though connections are present in network , I can see in this window

```
 nm-connection-editor
```

after restarting i have to reset the /etc/network/interfaces file to default to make my network manager work
what am i doing wrong, i want to set the static ip address permanent

need help

Comment: Where did you get these addresses from? gateway can NOT be `192.168.1.255`, etc. And why dns server is localhost?

Comment: ifconfig  shows eth0 connection i taken from there

Comment: It is a broadcast address, not a gateway

Comment: ohkk  so where can i get gateway

Comment: To get to know the correct gateway, set address to auto, connect and look int `route -n`.

Comment: got it i will try new settings thanks for help

Comment: This looks correct. If you connect to a home router, you can use the same address as a dns server.

Comment: so i will default the /etc/network/interfaces and  edit setting from gui in nm  right ??   no its not home router

Comment: Using NM is better. If it is not a router, you need to find dns server too.

Comment: auto lo
     should be auto eth 0  right i am using ethernet

Comment: The file should read exactly as in my answer. No `eth0` there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you edit `/etc/network/interfaces`, Network Manager does not manage the interface. It is designed this way.

You can setup a static address in NM. There is an option to set a static address. Why edit the file?

Return the file to

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

and you  will be able to use NM.

So you need to choose how you want to manage the network: using Network Manager or using `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

Comment: i tried to setup static id using gui in nm but than my internet was not working   than i  visit youtube to set static ip and most of them do this way

Comment: It means that you setup it wrong. You config is crap.

Comment: nope internet was working with this config but when i tried reboot after some other change where reboot required than  nm stoped working

Comment: It did not work with this config? You need to restart network after you edit the file or reboot. You've just spoiled the file and it came into effect after a reboot.

Comment: it was working with that config